# What is the latest jar version for jackson-all and jackson-mapper-asl?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

What is the latest jar version for jackson-all and jackson-mapper-asl? I had the jackson-all-1.9.9.jar and jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, but I am not sure they are the latest ones, please advise me, thank you

Answer (score 5):

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl you're using the outdated `org.codehaus.jackson.*` versions and should be using the new `com.fasterxml.jackson.*` versions.

Comment: Thanks for your help here, I am not clear,  I already had latest jackson-core-2.8.1.jar,jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar, jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar for my project, but how about jackson-mapper-asl one? you mean  jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar will not be used?

Comment: Yes, `jackson-mapper-asl` was *replaced* by `jackson-databind`, which you're already using, so you should be fine removing the older dependency. As an example, all Spring Boot's dependencies to jackson are to `com.fasterxml.*` artifacts. If in doubt, you can always try to remove all your `import org.codehaus.jackson.*` clauses from your classes and see if they still work (you might need to adapt some code to newer interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-mapper-asl:2.9.8 will be the new dependency